# How to get max date from any date field in moment js

Tags: momentjs

How to extract max date from date field by using any function in moment js?

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can help

```
var a = moment().subtract(1, 'day');
var b = moment().add(1, 'day');

moment.min(a, b); // where a, b are moment objects
output: a

moment.max(a, b);
output: b
```

Comment: my requirement is to pick the data from date field not from calendar date.

Comment: @Tulu ok, can you please explain more about the flow how you want to proceed, because you want to pick the date from date field which gives you one value. and you want a max. So a little bit more description can help to come with a better solution